# If I mix carbon dioxide and sodium hydroxide in the right amounts in water, do I get baking soda?

Tags: acid-base, aqueous-solution, ionic-compounds

Suppose I need a sodium bicarbonate solution (for non-food related reasons). Can I get something resembling it by mixing $\ce{NaOH}$ and $\ce{CO2}$ in water?

Of course one should not attempt to make food in a chemistry lab, so lets rule out the food safety requirements for food-grade baking soda.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is certainly one method by which sodium bicarbonate can be produced.  According to [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_bicarbonate#Production):

> $\ce{NaHCO3}$ may be obtained by the reaction of carbon dioxide with an aqueous solution of sodium hydroxide. The initial reaction produces sodium carbonate:
>
> $$\ce{CO2 + 2 NaOH → Na2CO3 + H2O}$$
>
> Further addition of carbon dioxide produces sodium bicarbonate, which at sufficiently high concentration will precipitate out of solution:
>
> $$\ce{Na2CO3 + CO2 + H2O → 2 NaHCO3}$$

The net reaction for this two-step process is then simply:

$$\ce{CO2 + NaOH -> NaHCO3}$$

Note that this is not the common method by which sodium bicarbonate is produced commercially, but it is a perfectly valid method of it's synthesis.